# Perl to format XML data

Tags: xml, perl

How can I use Perl to make XML data readable?  The source is one-line.  I need to format it. For example:

```
<data><project>1234</project></data>
```

convert to

```
<data>
    <project>
       1234
    </project>
</data>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have `xmllint` already installed on your system:

```
$ xmllint --format file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <project>1234</project>
</data>
```

[XML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTidy) is another option.  Refer to the `bin/xmltidy` script.

[xml_pp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?xml_pp) is yet another option (`XML::Twig`).

Other CPAN modules may also have this capability.  Search for these terms: pretty, format, indent, ident, tidy, serial.

Comment: Another possibility: `XML::LibXML`'s `serialize(1)` method: `perl -MXML::LibXML -e 'print XML::LibXML->new->parse_string(shift)->serialize(1)' '<data><project>1234></project></data>'`

Comment: @choroba Yes, this oneliner returns four lines, just like the `xmllint --format` in the answer. XML::LibXML 2.0019, libxml2-2.7.8_5.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: It works for `serialize(1)`, but not (2). If I add text after `</project>`, it does not format at all... latest XML::LibXML, libxml2-2.7.8.

Comment: thanks. How is the performance ? if we have 1GB data, how long it will take ? In the real work, is it good solution ?

Comment: @user595234: 1GB? Better to use a pull parser, then.

Comment: @choroba That's true, serialize(2) does not work anymore. This broke between libxml2 2.7.6 and 2.7.8. XML::LibXML cannot do anything about it (other to fix the documentation).